# Let New Users Connect with Twitter OAuth only (not Facebook)

Tags: users, social-network, authentication-authorization

I would like to let new users register with a Twitter OAuth for new' signups' to my project so not really wishing for Facebook implementation as yet. There seems to be a range of subjects & options via Drupal.org etc, but I'm simply looking for a quick and easy 'out of the box' solution to getting this going without having to waste lots of time trying to figure out which route to go. I already have a Twitter account so just need a pointer to best 'free' option geared towards Twitter for signup purposes to my projects. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into [HybridAuth Social Login](https://drupal.org/project/hybridauth)

> This module integrates HybridAuth library into Drupal and allows your
>   users to login and register using:
>
> Facebook Twitter Google LinkedIn Foursquare Yahoo Windows Live MySpace
>   AOL OpenID Github, LastFM, Vimeo, Disqus, Instagram, Viadeo, Identica,
>   Tumblr, Goodreads, QQ, Sina, Murmur, Pixnet, Plurk, Skyrock, 500px,
>   Vkontakte, Mail.ru, Yandex, Odnoklassniki, Twitch.tv, Steam and more

You can select which all social logins you want to enable. So if you are just looking for twitter you can enable that alone.

Comment: https://drupal.org/project/hybridauth looks definately the best option for me, and 'ticks all the boxes', so I'll go down that route (Open source, Bootstrap style also.. great! so 5 stars on that one!). Thanks @mohammed-shameem for the great tip. All the best.

Comment: Good to know that it helped.